# XUnit requires too many arguments

Tags: f#, xunit.net

I have an xUnit test that accepts three arguments, a list, an integer and a tuple, however, when I run it it's failing with the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The test method expected 4 parameter values, but 3 parameter values were provided.
```

There are only three items in the test data I'm providing.

```ml
<AbstractClass>]
type TestCases (data: seq<obj[]>) = 
    member this.Data = data

    interface IEnumerable<obj[]> with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = this.Data.GetEnumerator()

    interface IEnumerable with
        member this.GetEnumerator() = (this :> IEnumerable).GetEnumerator()

type SplicingTestCases () =
    inherit TestCases (seq {
        yield [|box [1; 2; 3; 4;]; 
                box 2; 
                box ([1;2;],[3;4;])
                |]
        })

[<Theory>]
[<ClassData(typeof<SplicingTestCases>)>]
let ``Splicing`` testList index expected =
    let actual = testList |> splice index
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual)
```

I've exec tried removing a parameter (just to see what happens) like this:

```ml
let ``Splicing`` testList index =
    let actual = testList |> splice index
    Assert.Equal(actual, actual)
```

Now the error is:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The test method expected 2 parameter values, but 3 parameter values were provided.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: using 2+, `MemberData` generally works well. Best to use the tupled arg syntax though:- `let Splicing (testList, index) =` and either pin the types in the arglist  `(testListindex : int)` or hover over them to make sure they are correct

Comment: You mean change the method signature for the SUT?

Comment: no, the Test Method - as it is, type inference will decide the types. If you excplicitly declare and make it tupled args then there's less things to go wrong

Comment: @RubenBartelink Ah, I have done that in places.  It's solved some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the tuple is being converted into two separate objects.  Not sure yet if this is happening in the F# compilation of in xUnit's interpretation of the tuple.

Yielding the following works though:

```
[|box [1; 2; 3; 4;]; 
  box 2; 
  box [1;2;];
  box [3;4;];|]
```